# Passing value to previous widget

Tags: flutter

I have simple form , inside it have CircularAvatar when this is pressed show ModalBottomSheet to choose between take picture from gallery or camera. To make my widget more compact , i separated it to some file.

1. FormDosenScreen (It's main screen)
2. DosenImagePicker (It's only CircularAvatar)
3. ModalBottomSheetPickImage (It's to show ModalBottomSheet)

[image]
[image]

The problem is , i don't know how to passing value from **ModalBottomSheetPickImage** to **FormDosenScreen**. Because value from **ModalBottomSheetPickImage** i will use to insert operation.

I only success passing from third Widget to second Widget , but when i passing again from second Widget to first widget the value is null, and i think the problem is passing from Second widget to first widget.

How can i passing from third Widget to first Widget ?

## First Widget

```
class FormDosenScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeNamed = '/formdosen-screen';

  @override
  _FormDosenScreenState createState() => _FormDosenScreenState();
}

class _FormDosenScreenState extends State<FormDosenScreen> {
  String selectedFile;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final detectKeyboardOpen = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
    print('trigger');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Tambah Dosen'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton(
            itemBuilder: (_) => [
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text('Tambah Pelajaran'),
                value: 'add_pelajaran',
              ),
            ],
            onSelected: (String value) {
              switch (value) {
                case 'add_pelajaran':
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(FormPelajaranScreen.routeNamed);
                  break;
                default:
              }
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                DosenImagePicker(onPickedImage: (file) => selectedFile = file),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Card(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextFormFieldCustom(
                          onSaved: (value) {},
                          labelText: 'Nama Dosen',
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        TextFormFieldCustom(
                          onSaved: (value) {},
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                          labelText: 'Email Dosen',
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        TextFormFieldCustom(
                          onSaved: (value) {},
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          inputFormatter: [
                            // InputNumberFormat(),
                            WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                          ],
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.local_phone),
                          labelText: 'Telepon Dosen',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: kToolbarHeight),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            child: Visibility(
              visible: detectKeyboardOpen > 0 ? false : true,
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print(selectedFile);
                },
                materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                color: colorPallete.primaryColor,
                child: Text(
                  'SIMPAN',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: AppConfig.headerFont),
                ),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
              ),
            ),
            bottom: kToolbarHeight / 2,
            left: sizes.width(context) / 15,
            right: sizes.width(context) / 15,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Second Widget

```
class DosenImagePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(String file) onPickedImage;
  DosenImagePicker({@required this.onPickedImage});
  @override
  DosenImagePickerState createState() => DosenImagePickerState();
}

class DosenImagePickerState extends State<DosenImagePicker> {
  String selectedImage;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () async {
          await showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => ModalBottomSheetPickImage(
              onPickedImage: (file) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedImage = file;
                  widget.onPickedImage(selectedImage);
                  print('Hellooo dosen image picker $selectedImage');
                });
              },
            ),
          );
        },
        child: CircleAvatar(
          foregroundColor: colorPallete.black,
          backgroundImage: selectedImage == null ? null : MemoryImage(base64.decode(selectedImage)),
          radius: sizes.width(context) / 6,
          backgroundColor: colorPallete.accentColor,
          child: selectedImage == null ? Text('Pilih Gambar') : SizedBox(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Third Widget

```
class ModalBottomSheetPickImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(String file) onPickedImage;

  ModalBottomSheetPickImage({@required this.onPickedImage});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                final String resultBase64 =
                    await commonFunction.pickImage(quality: 80, returnFile: ReturnFile.BASE64);
                onPickedImage(resultBase64);
              },
              child: CircleAvatar(
                foregroundColor: colorPallete.white,
                backgroundColor: colorPallete.green,
                child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                final String resultBase64 =
                    await commonFunction.pickImage(returnFile: ReturnFile.BASE64, isCamera: false);
                onPickedImage(resultBase64);
              },
              child: CircleAvatar(
                foregroundColor: colorPallete.white,
                backgroundColor: colorPallete.blue,
                child: Icon(Icons.photo_library),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This a problem about state management. You can easily do that using Provider or Bloc. See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options The easy way to do this is through Provider. If you want me to show you how to use Provider, I'll write an answer.

Comment: Can't you just create a simple [callback](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/working-with-callback-in-flutter-89dc207cba37#:~:text=If%20we%20go%20by%20definition,action%20when%20we%20require%20it.&text=For%20Example%2C%20if%20you%20are,then%20what%20would%20you%20do%3F)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest and easiest way to do this is through Provider. It is one of the state management solutions you can use to pass values around the app as well as rebuild only the widgets that changed. (Ex: When the value of the Text widget changes). Here is how you can use Provider in your scenario:

This is how your model should look like:

```
class ImageModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _base64Image;
  get base64Image => _base64Image;
  set base64Image(String base64Image) {
    _base64Image = base64Image;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add getters and setters so that you can use notifyListeners() if you have any ui that depends on it.

Here is how you can access the values of ImageModel in your UI:

```
final model=Provider.of<ImageModel>(context,listen:false);
String image=model.base64Image; //get data
model.base64Image=resultBase64; //set your image data after you used ImagePicker
```

Here is how you can display your data in a Text Widget (Ideally, you should use Selector instead of Consumer so that the widget only rebuilds if the value its listening to changes):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 //other widgets
 Selector<ImageModel, String>(
  selector: (_, model) => model.base64Image,
  builder: (_, image, __) {
   return Text(image);
     },
   );
  }
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this easily. If you are using Blocs.