# Flutter - Triggering another widgets method which widget is in another file

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am currently learning Flutter and stuck on this one. I am new to programming as well so please be gentle on explanations :).

I am trying to build a website for myself as a learning project. Website will be made of 2 widgets in general. An AppBar and a PageView for 3 pages. I created this;

[image: websitelayout]

Now, header and body are seperate files as you can see from these 2 files.

[image: bodyfile]

[image: headerfile]

I want to trigger previous or next page buttons from header also. I will connect them to their page numbers but I want to figure out how I can manage to do it from header.

Thank you.

Comment: This can be done through State Management. Check this out: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options I couldn't make an answer here because it is going to be hard for me to explain it in just one answer. You might want to check this out but instead of a String that you are sharing, you can use a function without the get and set methods. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63444457/passing-value-to-previous-widget/63444588#63444588

Comment: I was going to learn provider next. Should I just go for it and learn how to implement it for this situation?

Comment: Yes. It would be a great idea. State management is extremely important. You would have trouble passing around data to multiple screens without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem as following;

Created a class for containing page number and notify listeners for page changes.

```
class PageState extends ChangeNotifier {
  var _currentpage = 0;

  setPage(int pageNum) {
    if (pageNum != _currentpage) {
      _currentpage = pageNum;
      print(currentPage);
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  int get currentPage => _currentpage;
}
```

Created a listener for current page change on body part as follows;

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var statepage = Provider.of<PageState>(context, listen: false);

    void goToPage() {
      pageStateControl.animateToPage(statepage.currentPage,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeInCubic);
    }

    statepage.addListener(goToPage);
```

Whenever page number changes statepage listener triggers goToPage method inside of pageview widget file.